# How To change the image when each text div is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have implemented an image slider which changes the image when the buttons are pressed!

now i wanna implement the change of image to occur when the div is clicked. Each div displays different image.I know there is an onclick function using Javascript. But How to implement it.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <title>W3.CSS</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
    <body>

    <h2 class="w3-center">Manual Slideshow</h2>

    <div class="w3-content w3-display-container" style=" width :939px; 
    height:359px; border: 2px solid black;">
    <img class="mySlides" src="C:\wamp64\www\test\My Works\images\1.jpg" 
    style="width:638px;height:355px">
    <img class="mySlides" src="C:\wamp64\www\test\My Works\images\2.jpg" 
    style="width:638px;height:355px;">

    <div class = "texts">

    <div class = "text1" style="width: 298px; height: 127px;  border: 1px solid 
    red; text-align: center;padding-top: 26px; position: absolute; right:     
    0px; top:0px;"> Lorem Ipsum Is Lorem Ipsum <br> Lorem Ipsum Is Lorem Ipsum
    </div>

    <div class = "text2" style="width: 297px; height: 120px;  border: 1px solid 
    red; text-align: center;padding-top: 26px; position: absolute; right:     
    0px; top:127px;"> Lorem Ipsum Is Lorem Ipsum <br> Lorem Ipsum Is Lorem Ipsum
    </div>

    <div class = "text3" style="width: 297px; height: 111px;  border: 1px solid 
    red; text-align: center;padding-top: 26px; position: absolute; right:     
    0px; top:245px;"> Lorem Ipsum Is Lorem Ipsum <br> Lorem Ipsum Is Lorem Ipsum
    </div>

    </div>



   <button class="w3-button w3-black w3-display-left" 
   onclick="plusDivs(-1)">&#10094;</button>
   <button class="w3-button w3-black w3-display-right" 
   onclick="plusDivs(1)">&#10095;</button>
   </div>
```

[image: Picture of image slider]

Comment: why don't you show us what you have coded?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the relevant code. If you've already managed to implement a working slider that accepts clicks on the `<` and `>` buttons then don't you know how to do click event handlers?

Comment: Paste your code here, use the 7th icon of the editor of stackoverflow to paste html, javascript, ...

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/AwadheshVerma/hhL7ch5o/ please have a look and try to this I think that is help full

Answer (score 2):

Using javascript you can change the `src` attribute of the `img` tag on a `div` click like this.

**HTML**

```
<div onclick="changeImage('image1.jpg');">Div one</div>
<div onclick="changeImage('iamge2.jpg');">Div two</div>
<img src="" alt="Image" id="myImg">
```

**Javascript**

```
function changeImage(image){
    document.getElementById('myImg').src = image;
}
```

And by using JQuery do it like this.

```
<div class="one">Div one</div>
<div class="two">Div two</div>
<img src="" alt="Image" id="myImg">

$('.one').on('click', function(){
    $('#myImg').attr('src', 'image1.jpg');
});
$('.two').on('click', function(){
    $('#myImg').attr('src', 'image2.jpg');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

this only show you how to change the image
change the triger from button to your div id

```js
$("#mybutton").click(function(){
    $("#img_1").attr('src','https://www.google.com.pk/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_120x44dp.png');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div><img id="img_1" src='https://www.google.com.pk/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png'></div>
<button id="mybutton">click me</button>
```

see this is working

Comment: this is implemented using the button.. I need to do the function while clicking on the text div

Comment: i have update my ans check that just change the id from click function like $(".text1").click(function(){}) this is what you want

Answer (score 0):

Since I can't comment yet, use code.rider's answer and change this line:

```
$("#mybutton").click(function(){
```

to this

```
$("#myDiv").click(function(){
```

This will tell jQuery to listen to clicks on the div instead of a button.